# Type erasure - Generics - getting ClassCastException not where expected

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I was going through this page, just playing with the examples it provides.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html

I am using Java 8.

According to this tutorial page, the `ClassCastException` should be thrown at that line 200, but actually it's thrown earlier - at the line marked as 100. Why?! Is the tutorial outdated (not applicable to Java 8)?

Then I asked for all methods of `n` and I can see the method `setData(Object)` is there, it's in the Object pointed to by `n` (this is the so-called bridge method, I assume).

OK, so why do I get the exception at the line marked as 100? Is the compiler transforming my set call to this `n.setData((Integer)"Hello");` If so, seems the tutorial is outdated indeed.

Could anyone explain this?

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Test010 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyNode mn = new MyNode(5);
        Node n = mn; // A raw type - compiler throws an unchecked warning
        Method meth[] = n.getClass().getMethods();
        n.setData("Hello"); // 100 //
        System.out.println("001");
        Integer x = mn.data; // 200 // // Causes a ClassCastException to be thrown.
    }

}

class Node<T> {

    public T data;

    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        System.out.println("Node.setData");
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class MyNode extends Node<Integer> {

    public MyNode(Integer data) {
        super(data);
    }

    public void setData(Integer data) {
        System.out.println("MyNode.setData");
        super.setData(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

OK, well, I figured it out shortly after posting the question here.

Actually the exception thrown at line 200: this is not a fact, the tutorial is just hypothetically mentioning that. Further down in the tutorial, it's clear that the bridge `setData` method contains a type cast to `Integer`.

```
public void setData(Object data) {
    setData((Integer) data);
}
```

That's what's causing my problem and my confusion.

In any case, this tutorial page seems a bit confusing, but OK, maybe it's just me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm inclined to say that the tutorial is just wrong.  It would be correct if class `MyNode` were not involved, or if `MyNode` inherited `Node<T>` generically, instead of specifying by the type parameter concretely.  Once `MyNode` defines a specific value for the type parameter, however, type erasure no longer applies to it.

Comment: Now you got me even more confused shortly after I thought I figured it out :)

Comment: @peter.petrov, I don't think I said anything that conflicts with your own answer.  An exception is, and always has been, thrown at the line marked `100` in your question.  Although type erasure does not directly apply to class `MyNode`, the tutorial is pointing out that it must accommodate the type erasure that *does* apply to class `Node`.  To handle that, the compiler synthesizes a bridge method.

Comment: I see... OK, this comment makes it a bit clearer for me, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the tutorial confuses me a lot. the comments in the following code doesn't indicate what happens when jvm executes these codes.

```java
MyNode mn = new MyNode(5);
Node n = mn;            // A raw type - compiler throws an unchecked warning
n.setData("Hello");     
Integer x = mn.data;    // Causes a ClassCastException to be thrown.
```

It's just assumed that setData in Node was not overridden.

But actually the bridge method overrides the setData in Node and made it seems like it was overridden by the setData in MyNode.

And that will be more like a polymorphism is such a case.